# Blackberry HTTP Header

Tags: iis, browser, blackberry

I'm trying to access an internal website that requires windows authentication. I've tried going to the website on my Blackberry but get the following error:

> You are not authorized to view this
>   page.
>
> You do not have permission to view
>   this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied because
>   your web browser is sending a
>   WWW-authenticate header field that the
>   web server is not configured to accept

So how do i change my browser to send a different header field, or how do I make the web server accept a Blackberry header?

This is nearly over my head, so don't get to technical. Tell me if I need to give more info.

I'm running this on an IIS server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out what's in the WWW-Authenticate header sent by the BlackBerry (check the web server request logs or sniff the HTTP traffic). It may be that the BlackBerry is trying to authenticate using the "Basic" HTTP authentication scheme, whereas the web server rejects this scheme, say, because it's very insecure.